# QGIS and GRASS 7 integration

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, installation

I want to integrate QGIS 2.12.3 or 2.13 with GRASS 7, but I still haven't been able to do so.

Can someone please tell me how can I do this with a stable QGIS version.